# How to get multiple column name from single join in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Not sure about the title of the question its right/wrong.

I have two tables

```
Category: CategoryID,CategoryName ,ParentCategoryID
ref_Product_Category: CategoryID, ProductID
```

I have written a query like this,

```
 SELECT  R.productID,
         C.ParentCategoryID,
         C.categoryName

 FROM    Category C 
         INNER JOIN ref_Product_Category R
            ON C.categoryID = R.categoryID
```

So it returned me 4 columns in the result, But now I want another column which will contain
the ParentCategoryID's category name. 
I am not sure how to do it. Category table is self referencing table.

Comment: Is it not c.categoryname and I'm assuming this is in mssql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `Left outer join` on the table itself (so we do not lose any rows if `INNER JOIN` is used and no `ParentCategoryID` is specified):

```
SELECT  R.productID,
         C.ParentCategoryID,
         C.categoryName,
         ISNULL(C1.CategoryName, '') as ParentCategoryName
 FROM    Category C 
         INNER JOIN ref_Product_Category R
            ON C.categoryID = R.categoryID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Category C1 on Category.ParentCategoryID = C1.CategoryID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT  R.productID,
         C.ParentCategoryID,
         C.categoryName,
         C.CategoryName,
         CP.CategoryName as ParentCategory
 FROM    Category C  
 INNER JOIN ref_Product_Category R ON C.categoryID = R.categoryID
 INNER JOIN Category CP ON Cp.CategoryID=C.ParentCategoryID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT  R.productID,
         C.ParentCategoryID,
         C.categoryName, p.ParentCategoryName

 FROM    Category C 
         INNER JOIN ref_Product_Category R
            ON C.categoryID = R.categoryID INNER JOIN ParentCategory p on p.ParentCategoryID=c.ParentCategoryID
```